# Impossible to scan with Canon Pixma TS5351?

Tags: windows-10, printer, scanner, canon-pixma

I am using the Canon TS5351 Printer and want to use the scanner. The manual says to download a software called "IJ Scan Utility", but trying to download from the official source it says ([Link](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_ts_series/pixma-ts5351.html?type=software&language=en&os=windows%20server%202003%20r2%20(32-bit)&softwaredescriptionid=tcm:14-1331737)):

> This software is not supported with the operating system selected and is not available for download.

I picked every Windows version from 10 to 7 and it says it for all of them. I never heard of such a a thing from any company... Anyone has experience? Do I need to go to a shady website and download the software? Thanks in advance...

I'm using Win-10 64bit

Comment: The website seems to be broken. Contact Canon support.

Comment: @PaulErlenmeyer Did you get this resolved?

Comment: @CobusKruger Yes, support has sent me a new link, that had the drivers including the software required to scan. Apparently the link that I provided was bad. Furthermore the driver installation links in the manual are wrong, since the mentioned software was not included in the installation pack linked in it.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so I know this is late but I've been struggling too and I think others might need to know this so here I am for future reference. So you you to the canon website and find your printer by searching TS5351 and you install the drivers from there. More specifically "TS5300 series Driver setup package." That will add Canon utilities to the start menu and THERE you will find IJ Scan Utility after restarting your computer.